# How to pack a transaction to be pushed to rpc using push_tranasction?

Tags: transactions, rpc, transfer

Im trying to figure out exactly what is expected to pack a transaction. I've written a class to pack my transaction based off of a couple of opensource projects I've seen. First of all is there any information as to was the requirements are to pack a transaction?

The error Im getting when trying to push_transaction is "Invalid Packed Transaction".

Updated version of my bytewriter and usage. Still getting error:
https://gist.github.com/ismyhc/8825bb4b560b061d91289967ddff45b7

Comment: Have you confirmed that you are packing the bytes in the correct "endian-ness"?

Comment: @JohnHaager
Thats a good question. Im writing this code in swift for iOS so I believe that its by default little-endian. What is the correct "endian-ness" ?

Comment: I believe it needs to be big endian.

Comment: It needs to be little endian

Comment: Thanks, I finally got everything working late last week. I will be posting an updated version of my swift bytewriter and usage soon.

Comment: @ismyhc I guess you got this working. I am facing issues related to this for larger payload transactions which I didn't suffer previously for small transactions. Do you have any iOS specific code or pointers you are willing to share to get this working. I thought I could rely on the RPC endpoints for json_to_bin and don't quite understand why this doesn't work for this.

Comment: [EOS-Tutorials
](https://github.com/EOSBlock/EOS-Tutorials/blob/master/EN/transfer-tokens-using-RPC.md) This tutorial could be useful